# How to get the redirecting link of a link using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open the google scholar links in my html . As the Google scholar link is redirecting to the particular site(e.g abc.com). The abc.com is not opening in iframe. iframe display an error for that link: "refused to connect".

```
<iframe src="
http://scholar.google.se/scholar_url?url=https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/20193167581&hl=en&sa=X&d=11331141127468683170&scisig=AAGBfm0gdJ83JW1o6Xb82uD9bNnZNNTSeQ&nossl=1&oi=scholaralrt&hist=92LQev8AAAAJ:14285763116787501533:AAGBfm0HS_SbXaAMNGPcdwbkLaUuKU410g"></iframe>
```

How can i get the actual link abc.com using the Google scholar link:

The Sample Google link is:
http://scholar.google.se/scholar_url?url=https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/20193167581&hl=en&sa=X&d=11331141127468683170&scisig=AAGBfm0gdJ83JW1o6Xb82uD9bNnZNNTSeQ&nossl=1&oi=scholaralrt&hist=92LQev8AAAAJ:14285763116787501533:AAGBfm0HS_SbXaAMNGPcdwbkLaUuKU410g

And it is redirecting to the site:
https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/20193167581

Comment: Why you do not redirect directly to  https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/20193167581 ?

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/20193167581" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

Comment: The google scholar is not sending me the direct links. It sends only redirecting links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: Marked as duplicate as the question needs to get the `url` `GET` parameter from a string.

Comment: No sir. The URL GET variable also not working url=not the correct redirecting link

Comment: @SaddamAzad Yes it is. The `url` parameter in the Sample Google Scholar link is the exact same as the one you said you want... `url GET:` `url=https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/20193167581` ... See the link in there?

Comment: Ive added the get parameter as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect URL is stored in a GET parameter.

```
function getRedirectLink(link) {
  var url = new URL(link);
  var redirect = url.searchParams.get("url");
  return redirect
}
```